What are these strakes on the belly of the F-16 for?
What are these 2 things doing under the F-16? Are they for aerodynamics?

Source.

Does this answer your question?

Those are called Ventral Fins.  They provide more vertical tail area (for yaw stability, etc) particularly when the aircraft is at high angle of attack.
